# Check if user has comment on current post

Tags: custom-post-types, users, comments, array

Hello I have multiauthor website and I need to create a condition to check if defined user ***( no current user )*** has comment on current post.
Here is my code but I can not complete this

```
$userid = "444"; //this is the user that I need to Check if has comments on current post

$commenters = array("444", "544", "245", "453", "773", "990"); //here I need to get array of users ids who have comment in current post and check if user with the id 444 exist in this array
if(in_array($userid, $commenters)){ 
    echo " user with the id 444 have comment in current article";
}
else {
    echo "user with the id 444 have no comment in current article";
}
```

my problem is that how can I  get array of users ids who have comment in current post or do you have any better alternative to code. Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to create a condition to check if defined user ***( no current
> user )*** has comment on current post

For that purpose, you can just use [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) like so:

```php
$post_id = get_the_ID(); // or just set a specific post ID
$user_id = 444;

// Get the total number of comments by the above user on the above post only.
$comment_count = get_comments( array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'count'   => true,
) );

if ( $comment_count ) {
    echo "user $user_id has <b>$comment_count comments</b> on post $post_id";
} else {
    echo "user $user_id has not commented on post $post_id";
}
```

> how can I get array of users ids who have comment in current post

Just like the above example, you can also use `get_comments()` like so:

```php
$comments = get_comments( array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
) );

// Get the users who have commented on the above post and store their ID, if any,
// in $commenters.
$commenters = array();
foreach ( $comments as $comm ) {
    if ( $comm->user_id && ! in_array( $comm->user_id, $commenters ) ) {
        $commenters[] = $comm->user_id;
    }
}

if ( in_array( $user_id, $commenters ) ) {
    .. your code here.
} else ...
```

Comment: thank you so much. amazing